# CSRF token expiration with flask and wtform

Tags: ajax, security, flask, csrf

What is the best practice when it comes to CSRF token expiration?

Say a user is visiting a page (Jinja template) with a form, but tries to submit says form only n hours later. The CSRF token is obviously expired by then.

Of course I could stretch the token's lifespan, but I'm looking for a better way to do this.
Should I try and fetch a new token through an ajax request, before submitting the form with ajax?

Comment: You could fetch a new token, yes. This would be the most common approach. But the real question is - is it really needed? You could also change the token expiration time. If you are using `Flask-WTF` this can be done via `WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT`.

Comment: @Kruspe any ideas how much I can safely stretch the time limit? What's the good practice?

Comment: By default it is set to 1 hour (3600 seconds). This is enough for most web applications. Depending on what you're doing, you can expand this period. For banking applications, one hour might be way too much time. For internal control panels, that just run 24/7, you could enter values for a week or even more. Just have the security concerns in mind. You could also define your custom OnExpiredToken-Handler to check if the token is expired, but valid besides that, and then send a new one within the initial response.